# Bypass javascript errors for graceful degradation

Tags: javascript, graceful-degradation

I have a javascript function which is called onclick of a button. It is working fine in chrome and firefox. It basically places some validation checks, so that in case of incomplete information form is not submitted to the server.

My question is that if in some browser the javascript function has some syntax errors, how can I ignore the errors, so that validation function is bypassed, after all validation function is just to reduce invalid form submits and checks are also placed on the server.

Comment: Shouldn't you b avoiding the javascript function errors when you know there are some?

Comment: Fix the syntax errors... the **syntax** of JavaScript is pretty much the same in all browsers. One example that can cause errors are trailing commas in IE.

Comment: @FelixKling you yourself answered your own question.

Comment: Trailing commas are easy to fix... catching syntax errors is not easy (is it even possible?). The code is parsed *before* it is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its very unlikely (if not impossible), that you write some ECMAscript code which works fine on some engines and throws syntax errors on others. Unless you're dealing with something like IE4 or real old Netscape browsers.

However, you can of course always wrap your code into `try..catch` blocks, like

```
try {
   // beautiful javascript code
} catch( ex ) {
   alert(ex.message);
}
```

Comment: ...and it will throw an exception under IE, because of the `console`. :]

Comment: `console.log`: O hai! IE9 without open console: BOOM!

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov `if (window.console) {...}`

Comment: @Christoph `((window.console && console.log) || alert)(ex.message)`

Comment: @qwertymk looks nice;) What about `var notify = ((window.console && console.log) || alert); notify(ex.message);`? Something like that would be neat.

Comment: @Christoph: It's usually a much better approach to progressively enhance existant objects than introducing a new thing. I usually go for something like `if(!('console' in window))` { window.console = {};...` where `...` fills all known properties with functions (those could of course call `alert` then instead).

Comment: @jAndy well, you could argue about that... Although It might be okay to extend this hostobject, I have been sticking to my own convention of introducing a new property in my own namespace instead of extending a native or host object. Interesting article about this: http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/

Comment: @Christoph: we aren't really modifying a host object here. Its more like a polyfill if the `console` object is not present at all.